# Time calculation in SVPWM switching of 3 phase inverter

Tags: inverter, switching

This is a code I found from microchip's website.

```
void CalcRefVec( void )
;{ 
;    if( Vr1 >= 0 )
;        {       
;        // (xx1)
;        if( Vr2 >= 0 )
;            {
;            // (x11)
;            // Must be Sector 3 since Sector 7 not allowed
;            // Sector 3: (0,1,1)  0-60 degrees
;            T1 = Vr2
;            T2 = Vr1
;            CalcTimes();
;            dPWM1 = Ta
;            dPWM2 = Tb
;            dPWM3 = Tc
;            }
;        else
;            {            
;            // (x01)
;            if( Vr3 >= 0 )
;                {
;                // Sector 5: (1,0,1)  120-180 degrees
;                T1 = Vr1
;                T2 = Vr3
;                CalcTimes();
;                dPWM1 = Tc
;                dPWM2 = Ta
;                dPWM3 = Tb
;
;                }
;            else
;                {
;                // Sector 1: (0,0,1)  60-120 degrees
;                T1 = -Vr2;
;                T2 = -Vr3;
;                CalcTimes();
;                dPWM1 = Tb
;                dPWM2 = Ta
;                dPWM3 = Tc
;                }
;            }
;        }
;    else
;        {
;        // (xx0)
;        if( Vr2 >= 0 )
;            {
;            // (x10)
;            if( Vr3 >= 0 )
;                {
;                // Sector 6: (1,1,0)  240-300 degrees
;                T1 = Vr3
;                T2 = Vr2
;                CalcTimes();
;                dPWM1 = Tb
;                dPWM2 = Tc
;                dPWM3 = Ta
;                }
;            else
;                {
;                // Sector 2: (0,1,0)  300-0 degrees
;                T1 = -Vr3
;                T2 = -Vr1
;                CalcTimes();
;                dPWM1 = Ta
;                dPWM2 = Tc
;                dPWM3 = Tb
;                }
;            }
;        else
;            {            
;            // (x00)
;            // Must be Sector 4 since Sector 0 not allowed
;            // Sector 4: (1,0,0)  180-240 degrees
;            T1 = -Vr1
;            T2 = -Vr2
;            CalcTimes();
;            dPWM1 = Tc
;            dPWM2 = Tb
;            dPWM3 = Ta
;
;            }
;        }
;}
;
;
;void CalcTimes(void)
;{
;    T1 = PWM*T1
;    T2 = PWM*T2
;    Tc = (PWM-T1-T2)/2
;    Tb = Ta + T1
;    Ta = Tb + T2
;}
```

Code was originally from AN1162 from Microchip, Sensorless FOC of ACIM.

Vr1,Vr2,Vr3 are the reference voltages from inverse Clarke transform. But how are they calculating time here?

I've been trying to understand this for a while now.

Comment: Strange. I always thought, that SVPWM does inverse Clarke and PWM, so the input shall be alpha beta components from inverse Park transform.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič let's say I have the alpha and beta components. How do I calculate time for each vector(or duty cycle register value) from alpha, beta values?

Comment: If you get the source from the zip files, you'll see that this is actually implemented in assembly, and the assembly does not truely mimic the pseudo C code you've pasted. As to what it's doing... It's taking the Vrs and converting them into pwm periods... The difference in the Vrs being the difference in the pwm duties scaled to the voltages and pwm resolution.

Comment: The alpha and beta are converted to reference 3 phase votages in other code you haven't posted - calcref.s

Comment: @David Molony I get how Vrs are generated. What I'm having to trouble understanding is why Ta=Tb+T2. Ta shouldn't have anything to do with Tb.

Comment: @David Molony imagine if the reference space vector was just above alpha axis in sector 1. So, Vr1 is the largest along alpha axis. - Vr2 is approaching zero along - 60 degree line, - Vr3 is increasing along the 60 degree line. Then could you walk me through what would happen if this codes logic was to be followed?

Comment: @David Molony most of the literature I've read determine sector and times using the alpha and beta components directly. Is there a paper or something that I can refer?

Comment: What do you mean by times? I was assuming you meant duty cycle. All the major micro manufacturers have appnotes that explain it. I found infineon and renesas ones best. Normally alpha is made synched with one of the phases, you only need one phase to reconstruct all 3 voltages since you know they're 120 degrees apart.

Comment: Otherwise you'll have to sit down and run through what the actual assembly code is doing for each sector and consider only the differences in the pwm values finally generated. Most foc algorithms centre around 50%duty cycle so ta=tb=tc=50% = 0V to the motor. Hence they are co-dependent.